# Parse Brew Doctor Warnings with Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, homebrew

I want to parse brew doctor result of files into a ansible var list

Brew Doctor gives the following

```
Warning: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib...

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Homebrew...
```

I want to store these these files and iterate through them in ansible

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
vars:

  my_command: Brew-Doctor-List-Files-Command
  my_owner: Brew-Doctor-Files-Owner
  my_dirs: []

tasks:

  - set_fact:
      my_dirs: "{{ my_dirs + [ item ] }}"
    with_lines: "{{ my_command }}"
    when: item is search('^/usr/local/(.*)')

  - file:
      state: directory
      recurse: yes
      path: "{{ item }}"
      owner: "{{ my_owner }}"
    loop: "{{ my_dirs }}"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this:

```
vars:
  my_dirs: []

tasks:

  - name: set_fact IGNORE ERRORS  
    shell: brew doctor 
    register: doc_data 
    ignore_errors: yes 

  - name: setting facts for chown and chmod from brew doctor 
    set_fact: 
      my_dirs: "{{ my_dirs + [ item ] }}" 
    with_items: "{{ doc_data.stderr_lines }}" 
    when: item | regex_search('^/usr/local/(.*)')
```